# Call a userspace function from within a Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm programming a simple Linux character device driver to output data to a piece of hardware via I/O ports. I have a function which performs floating point operations to calculate the correct output for the hardware; unfortunately this means I need to keep this function in userspace since the Linux kernel doesn't handle floating point operations very nicely.

Here's a pseudo representation of the setup (note that this code doesn't do anything specific, it just shows the relative layout of my code):

**Userspace function**:

```
char calculate_output(char x){
    double y = 2.5*x;
    double z = sqrt(y);
    
    char output = 0xA3;

    if(z > 35.67){
        output = 0xC0;
    }
    
    return output;
}
```

**Kernelspace code**:

```
unsigned i;
for(i = 0; i < 300; i++){
    if(inb(INPUT_PORT) & NEED_DATA){
        char seed = inb(SEED_PORT);
        char output = calculate_output(seed);
        outb(output, OUTPUT_PORT);
    }

    /* do some random stuff here */
}
```

I thought about using `ioctl` to pass in the data from the userspace function, but I'm not sure how to handle the fact that the function call is in a loop and more code executes before the next call to `calculate_output` occurs.

The way I envision this working is:

1. main userspace program will start the kernelspace code (perhaps via `ioctl`)
2. userspace program **blocks** and waits for kernelspace code

   - kernelspace program *asks* userspace program for output data, and **blocks** to wait
   - userspace program **unblocks**, calculates and sends data (`ioctl`?), then **blocks** again
   - kernelspace program **unblocks** and continues
3. kernelspace program finishes and *notifies* userspace
4. userspace **unblocks** and continues to next task

So how do I have the communication between kernelspace and userspace, and also have blocking so that I don't have the userspace continually polling a device file to see if it needs to send data?

---

A caveat: while fixed point arithmetic would work quite well in my example code, it is not an option in the real code; I require the large range that floating point provides and -- even if not -- I'm afraid rewriting the code to use fixed point arithmetic would obfuscate the algorithm for future maintainers.

Comment: Any chance you can have almost everything in userspace, and just a thin interface enabler in the kernel?

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's what I'm trying to achieve. The stuff that occurs within the for loop is more miscellaneous hardware output (simple outb calls and nothing else).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Oh wait, do you mean moving the `for` loop outside the kernel?

Comment: It is possible to send signal and execute user-space applications, but it is not a common interface to use.
Do you plan to have a kernel thread executing something that requires user-space data? In this case you could write to a kfifo from the users-space trough write/ioctl, and then read this data from your kernel thread. No block needed.

Comment: There's no need for user-space data -- the algorithm to calculate the output byte just happens to involve several thousand lines of nested floating point operations (it's a robotic vision program). I'm unfamiliar with kfifo; is that some sort of queue structure in Linux?

Comment: You have an XY question.  Seems like you're stuck because you insist on doing a control loop in the kernel (instead of in userspace).  If you had just `read()` and `write()` driver operations for your I/O ports, then you could move everything to userland.  Or are there some timing issues?

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't mean to imply that I want a solution for my specific programming task; the thought of communicating to the userspace program came up during my brainstorming and I'm just curious if this is possible and how so -- not whether it is a practical solution or not. More than likely, I will revert to simple `read` and `write` calls.

Comment: IMO the preference should always be to put as much in userland as possible.  Userland code tends to be more portable.  Consider the scenario of the original HW platform goes out of production (I've seen this happen just a few years ago). The replacement HW platform is faster, cheaper and a different arch -- meaning a new kernel.  Therefore, the less non-HW-specific customization you put in the kernel the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to create a character device in your kernel driver, with your own file operations for a virtual file.  Then userspace can open this device `O_RDWR`.  You have to implement two main file operations:

- `read` -- this is how the kernel passes data back up to userspace.  This function is run in the context of the userspace thread calling the `read()` system call, and in your case it should block until the kernel has another seed value that it needs to know the output for.
- `write`-- this is how userspace passes data into the kernel.  In your case, the kernel would just take the response to the previous read and pass it onto the hardware.

Then you end up with a simple loop in userspace:

```
while (1) {
    read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
    calculate_output(buf, output);
    write(fd, output, sizeof output);
}
```

and no loop at all in the kernel -- everything runs in the context of the userspace process that is driving things, and the kernel driver is just responsible for moving the data to/from the hardware.

Depending on what your "do some random stuff here" on the kernel side is, it might not be possible to do it quite so simply.  If you really need the kernel loop, then you need to create a kernel thread to run that loop, and then have some variables along the lines of `input_data`, `input_ready`, `output_data` and `output_ready`, along with a couple of waitqueues and whatever locking you need.

When the kernel thread reads data, you put the data in `input_ready` and set the `input_ready` flag and signal the input waitqueue, and then do `wait_event(<output_ready is set>)`.  The `read` file operation would do a `wait_event(<input_ready is set>)` and return the data to userspace when it becomes ready.  Similarly the `write` file operation would put the data it gets from userspace into `output_data` and set `output_ready` and signal the output waitqueue.

Another (uglier, less portable) way is to use something like `ioperm`, `iopl` or `/dev/port` to do everything completely in userspace, including the low-level hardware access.

Comment: I ended up implementing essentially what is described here, albeit using `read`/`write` on a **sysfs** attribute rather than on a character device node.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you move the code that does all the "heavy lifting" to user mode - that is, calculate all the 300 values in one go, and pass those to the kernel.

I'm not even sure you can let an arbitrary piece of code call user-mode from the kernel. I'm sure it's possible to do, because that's what for example "signal" does, but I'm far from convinced you can do it "any way you like" (and almost certainly, there are restrictions regarding, for example, what you can do in that function). It certainly doesn't seem like a great idea, and it would DEFINITELY be quite slow to call back to usermode many times.

Comment: Unfortunately the execution sequence cannot be changed, which is what makes moving the loop to userspace difficult. I've adjusted my example code to reflect the sequential dependence I'm facing (i.e. earlier hardware outputs may affect the input sent to the function).

Comment: Then I would suggest you find a way to perform your calculation (using fixed point or some such) in kernel - calling back for every byte into usermode is just not a good idea - it will take 10-100x longer than the calculations you show here.